# Using XEmbed with PyGTK destroys my embedding window (why?)

Tags: python, sockets, gtk, pygtk, x11

Before I get to my question, what I would like to do is embed a small (pyGTK) based window into another window (say xterm).

Using examples [socket.py and plug.py from documentation](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-PlugsAndSockets.html) I am able to successfully plug the "Hello world" window into my socket. However when I try to plug plug.py into another window, say xterm, I get nothing.

If I try to plug my socket into xterm I get a destroyed xterm and a new socket window.

So why is this happening? How do I fix it?

To reproduce:

1. [Grab socket.py and plug.py from documentation.](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-PlugsAndSockets.html)
2. Start an Xterm window.
3. Run `xwininfo -int` and click on the Xterm window.
4. `./plug.py <xid from above>` (Nothing happens)
5. `./socket.py <xid from above>` (Xterm is destroyed, socket appears)

Answer (score 0):

The correct usage of the plug.py and socket.py pair is either

```
 plug.py
 socket.py <plug id printed by plug.py>
```

or

```
 socket.py
 plug.py <socket id printed by socket.py>
```

Both parties create their own windows. You cannot use a third-party window such as `xterm` here.